# Publish Each Tweet as Wordpress Post

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter

I am trying to link a twitter account to wordpress. Ideally I would like to be able to make it so each new tweet automatically get posted to a wordpress site via the wordpress blogging function.

tl;dr Each tweet becomes blog post on wordpress site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Twitter Tools](http://alexking.org/projects/wordpress/readme?project=twitter-tools) integrates with Twitter by giving you the following functionality:

- Archive your Twitter tweets (downloaded every 10 minutes)
- Create a blog post from each of your tweets
- Create a daily or weekly digest post of your tweets
- Create a tweet on Twitter whenever you post in your blog, with a link to the blog post
- Post a tweet from your sidebar
- Post a tweet from the WP Admin screens
- Pass your tweets along to another service (via API hook)

Comment: Perfect. Super easy to set up and does exactly what I want it to do. Now I can Style it and have comments and all sorts of wonderful things! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [press release](http://techcrunch.com/2010/11/05/wordpress-blackbird-twitter/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Techcrunch+%28TechCrunch%29) on [Blackbird Pie](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-blackbird-pie/) - it's now enabled in all WP blogs.